# Help creating a boolean with curve

Tags: boolean-modifier

[image]

I want to create a wall with a doorway by boolean with the 2 objects in the screenshot. When I add the boolean modifier to the cube, I can't add the other object to the boolean. It says beneath the viewport "Failed to find '".

I created the doorway shape by creating a curve, extruding via the Object Data Properties, converting it to a mesh, and using Merge by Distance to clean it up. I've also tried using the extruded curve in the boolean and this doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the project:
[image]

Comment: Your blend file works ok for me, but I'm not sure why you're using a bezier curve for a simple shape like that? It's easier to use a cylinder, rotate it 90 degrees on the Y axis, delete the bottom half and extend it downwards. Then use the cylinder as the cutter. That will give much cleaner geometry.

Comment: @JohnEason In the screenshot he's trying to select the Bézier object in a modifier on the Bézier object itself - that won't work no matter how simple the object is.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you are working on the object "BézierCircle.001" in *Edit Mode*. This means you are trying to select it in the modifier of that door object. Of course you cannot choose the object itself to be cut out of itself. Delete the modifier on "BézierCircle.001" (switch to *Object Mode* for that), then select the cube object and try again.

Comment: Yes indeed. You still get horrible geometry using a bezier converted to mesh though which is why I suggested using a modified cylinder. Look at his BezierCircle.001 which is the cutter in xray mode! Even the BezierCircle geometry is not good after cleanup! :^(

Comment: @JohnEason Yeah sure, but still this is a question for why it's not working and I won't lecture him what creates best geometry - which can get opinion-based really quick and wouldn't help with the actual problem, even with perfect geometry.

Comment: Fair enough. We'll leave it at that.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Please lecture! John, you said the BezierCircle's geometry isn't good after cleanup. How can I get a better result? I understand that using a cylinder would get me a better result in this case, but what if I wanted to have a more custom bezier shape as the cutter? How could I get better geometry in that case? Thanks!